# Validar atributo do tipo array em uma anotação

Tags: java, reflexão, atributos

Ao utilizar a anotação `Ordem` gostaria de tornar o seu atributo `valores` obrigatório. Por obrigatório quero dizer que o valor de seu atributo não deve aceitar um array vazio, ou um array com uma String vazia.

É possível realizar esse tipo de restrição no atributo de uma anotação ou esse tipo de restrição só é possível por meio de reflexão?

## Anotação Ordem:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Ordem {
    String[] valores();
}
```

## Valores não aceitos:

```
@Ordem(valores = {}) //array vazio
public class Foo1 {
    private String atributo;
}

@Ordem(valores = {""}) //array com elemento vazio
public class Foo2 {
    private String atributo;
}
```

## Valores aceitos:

```
@Ordem(valores = {"atributo"})
public class Foo3 {
    private String atributo;
}

@Ordem(valores = {"atributo1", "atributo2", "atributo3"})
public class Foo4 {
    private String atributo1;
    private String atributo2;
    private String atributo3;
}
```

Comment: É possível sim usando annotation processors, mas é um tanto difícil de implementar. Não possuo (ainda) o conhecimento necessário para isso, então deixo a dica como comentário ao invés de resposta. Se eu conseguir elaborar algo nisso, eu posto uma resposta.

Comment: Annotation processor, um [exemplo simples](http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/playing-with-java-annotation-processing.html). Mas eu não adicionaria esta complexidade com o fim de validar o conteúdo de um parâmetro. Ao invés, eu criaria uma anotação com nome expressivo no contexto indicando claramente o que deve ser passado, e validaria em tempo de execução quando estivesse lendo as anotações. Eventualmente, em vez de esperar um array "burro" como parâmetro você também pode criar uma tipo especial para este parâmetro que deixe mais evidente ao programador quais info são necessárias à anotação.

Comment: Permita-me perguntar a voce  @Victor Stafusa
No caso o annotation processor funciona apenas para anotacoes de Retention em Source, ou seja nao ficarcao disponiveis em Runtime, eh isso mesmo? Acredito que Geison Santos queira os valores da anotacao em Runtime, certo?

Comment: @FilipeGonzagaMiranda Funciona para Runtime também.

Comment: @GeisonSantos, atualizei a resposta, espero por favor me mande seu feedback, é sim possível solucionar usando recursos da Plataforma Java sem bibliotecas de terceiros

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No início quando você perguntou, eu de imediato, me lembrei das minhas próprias experiências criando anotações, e de como fui frustrado ao tentar criar uma anotação que tivesse uma validação contra seus possíveis valores, por isso minha primeira resposta, que está em destaque abaixo, contempla apenas as alternativas que eu mesmo adotei na época, que seriam usar uma versão diferente do compilador e/ou validar os valores das anotações em Runtime com unchecked Exceptions. Investigando mais a fundo descobri um recurso da plataforma Java SE disponível a partir da versão 1.6

**Annotation Processor - Java 1.6 ou >**

Está disponível a partir da versão 1.6, uma API que processa as anotações que você define para serem validadas em tempo de compilação, através de uma interface `Processor` e uma classe Abstrata `AbstractProcessor`

**Como funciona?**

Primeiramente, não é necessário nenhuma biblioteca de terceiros, algum plugin ou artifício, basta escrever seu próprio processor e utilizar ele ao compilar/processar suas classes que tenham as anotações. Nele você define quais anotações quer processar, e o que quer que ocorra, podendo até mesmo parar a compilação se não estiver de acordo com seus contratos, lançar warnings, ou gerar códigos. É possível ter mais de um Processor. Usando uma ferramento de controle de ciclos de projeto como Maven você vai poder aplicar seus processors.

**Então vamos ao seu caso**

Você quer validar o atributo valores, não pode ter Strings vazias ou nulas, não pode ter um array vazio, com tamanho(length) == 0

### A classe abaixo, faz o trabalho! Ela esta está no pacote ***default***(sem package definido) para facilitar o entendimento e o teste

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.processing.Messager;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes(value={"Ordem"})
public class MandatoryValuesAnnotationProcessor extends javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        System.out.println("/n/n Processing... /n Processing /n");

        Messager messager = processingEnv.getMessager();

        for (Element annotatedElement : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Ordem.class)){
            TypeElement typeElement = (TypeElement)annotatedElement;
            Ordem ordemAnnotation = typeElement.getAnnotation(Ordem.class);
            String valores[] = ordemAnnotation.valores();

            if(valores == null || valores.lenght == 0){
                messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Annotation Ordem nao pode ter valores vazios, nao pode ser um array vazio");
                return true;    
            }

            for (String valor : valores) {
                if(valor == null || valor.isEmpty()){
                    messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Annotation Ordem nao pode ter strings vazias ou nulas");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;//because we don't want other processors to process this annotations
    }

    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion(){
        return SourceVersion.latestSupported();
    }

}
```

Acima estamos definindo o Processor para suas classes com sua anotação, abaixo, usamos ele, já compilado para processar suas classes.

Compile sua anotação Ordem primeiro, se sequencia compile o processor, e então utilize-o para compilar as demais classes, como pode ver, essa não é a melhor maneira de gerenciar seus cliclos de compilção por isso recomendo que use Maven para construir seu projeto, ou outra solução. Você também pode criar um jar com seus processor, aqui está onde aprendi:

http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101/

**Para fins didáticos, use essa linha de comando ao compilar suas classes(é possível usar Maven também)**

```
javac -cp . -Xlint:processing -processor MandatoryValuesAnnotationProcessor -proc:only Foo2.java
```

Leia esta referência para um entendimento mais completo

[Referência](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#processing)

--

Nota: da resposta original, ainda é válido usar um compilador preparado, o que acaba não sendo o melhor, pois te dá menos flexibilidade e também é possível validar valores de atributos anotações em Runtime, o que é comum na plataforma SE e EE em algumas APIs, como **JAX-WS**, por exemplo

**Resposta Original**

Não, não é possível Geison, pelo menos não trabalhando apenas com o compilador da Oracle HotSpot, existem maneiras alternativas, como por exemplo, criar seu próprio compilador, ou customizar um do ***OpenJDK***.

Já tentei fazer isto que você quer fazer, além de outras coisas.

O que você pode fazer como alternativa é escrever um test unitário com JUnit que utilizando *Reflection*, verifica os valores definidos para esta anotação, não permitindo *arrays* vazios ou *Strings* vazias.

O que eu sempre fiz foi no momento que preciso ler os valores da anotação, se estes são mandatórios, eu lanço uma excessão - `IllegalArgumentException`
Onde aviso o programador que o valor definido não pode ser nulo ou vazio.

Comment: **Não, não é possível Geison, não existem maneiras para impor estar regras, a menos que você, crie seu próprio compilador, ou customize um do OpenJDK.** Isto está totalmente errado. Leia os comentários que fizeram na pergunta.

Comment: Oi @Edgar Muniz Berlinck, bom legal, acho que esse seu ponto é interessante, e nem te peço argumentos para defende-la, você tem total direito de achar errado customizar um compilador, mas aqui o objetivo é responder a pergunta, não defender opiniões. Customizar features da plataforma Java, é bem comum, i.e. JVM Zing, com o Garbage Collector sem pausas. Se quiser conversar me chama no chat. Só pra finalizar customizar cistomizar um compilador é uma das opções. Por favor não discuta isso aqui.

Comment: Você não entendeu: Você disse que a única maneira de se fazer isso é mudando a JDK. Eu estou falando pra você que que isto está errado, existe o Anotation Processor que foi feito para trabalhar com isso. Logo a sua resposta está errada apenas no ponto que eu citei.

Comment: Ahh, ok, ficou claro. Obrigado.

Comment: Então, e´só editar isso que fica ok :)

Comment: Feito,  @EdgarMunizBerlinck 
Mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: Acho a discussão aqui muito importante e fundamental para corrigir convicções equivocadas ou para esclarecer mal-entendidos.

Comment: @FilipeGonzagaMiranda relutei em dar sua resposta como certa por causa da afirmação que fez: uma afirmação forte. Afirmações fortes sempre devem ser seguidas de justificativas fortes. Parece-me, agora, que a resposta correta é de fato a sua. Utilizando os recursos comuns e ordinários da linguagem não é possível fazer o tipo de restrição descrito na pergunta. Para isto é necessário lançar mão de recursos mais complexos que fogem do uso corriqueiro da linguagem.

Comment: Obrigado pelos feedbacks. É com eles qie construíremos uma comunidade forte e concisa. Sim, tudo indica que sim, mas eu ainda vou fazer double check no annotation processor, não ficou claro pra mim. Parece que ele só processa anotação Retention.SOURCE, e não é isso que queremos, queremos que o processo ocorra com anotações Retention.RUNTIME

Comment: @FilipeGonzagaMiranda, tentei executar o exemplo com o comando javac -cp . -Xlint:processing -processor MandatoryValuesAnnotationProcessor -proc:only Foo2.java, mas não funcionou. Apresentou a mensagem "error: Annotation processor 'MandatoryValuesAnnotationProcessor.java' not found
warning: Annotation processing without compilation requested but no processors were found."

Comment: Você precisa compilar sua anotação, compilar seu processor e ai usar para compilar classes subsequentes. Por isso o ideal talvez para um projeto grande fosse você usar Maven para gerenciar isso, tem outra maneira tb que é criando um jar separado com seus processos e passar ele pro compilador, ou atualizar a resposta.